# Windows Session Recording Software

Tags: appsec, audit, logging

I'm trying to monitor connections and actions made by administrators (or any user connecting) to a server through TSE (i'm simplifying).

I've heard about a software which can record a video of any TSE session (you can define framerate of the capture) started on a server (an Agent has to be installed on the target server). It is called "Observe-IT".

Do you know any similar solutions so that i can compare it to Observe-IT ?
Solution can be a Session video recorder, or any other software that would allow me to monitor all actions made on a server, including in a graphical manner.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you even confirmed that Observe IT fullfills your requirements?  If you have not, then why are you looking for alternatives to Observe IT, instead of testing observe IT?

Comment: Citrix have something called IRIS but of course it works with ICA sessions rather than RDP.

Comment: @Ramhound : Observe IT fullfills my requirements, but i dont know any other software i can compare it to.

Comment: @GrahamHill : from what i've red, IRIS is now called SmartAuditor and is part of Citrix XenApp, but it's not working with Citrix XenDesktop currently...

Answer (score 1):

ManicTime records video of session activities and indexes the video with the time sequence of active applications. It is free for personal use but not for commercial use. It is not a keylogger. If this category of software would meet your requirements, you can find a few similar products at alternativeto.net.

There is also the category of software designed to enable employers to monitor employees' acceptable use of computers. A [recent answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11117) here on security.se uses the example of the "SPECTOR PRO" product.

Returning to ManicTime, it is primarily designed for one to track one's own use of one machine. However, I see that it has several features that may be useful for monitoring an untrusted user, or multiple machines, or both. It has options to suppress its system tray icon, encrypt its data with a password, and schedule local or remote backups of its data. It can be used in combination with a cost-free server product that aggregates data from ManicTime application instances. It can reportedly store 20 years' worth of data in one gigabyte.